# How to end loop with user input but not count it in the overall average of the numbers

Tags: python

I am currently studying C++ but my friend sometimes sends me his past papers from his python studies so that I can try them out. I am currently having a small problem with one of the final questions. I must add and find the average of the numbers entered and end the loop when the user enters a certain number eg:-200.

I managed to find the average but it includes the -200 in the average and how many numbers where entered. I tried breaking the loop before it adds the -200 to the list and I tried adding 200 after its been added to the loop but it they both did not work.
This is what I have so far:

```
avg = []
count = 0
while True:
    x = float(input('Enter a number(interger or float) :'))
    avg.append(x)
    count +=1

    if x == -999:

        list = avg 
        sum(list)
        len(list)
        avg = float(sum(list))/len(list)
        print ('The average of', count, 'is ' "%0.2f" % avg)
        break
```

Comment: You don't need to write stories in questions. Be precise!

Comment: Just after where you calculated average, you can use an if condition and check if the number which the user has entered is equal to the exit condition or not `if x == -200: break else  print ('The average of', count, 'is ' "%0.2f" % avg)`

Comment: Just do avg.append(x) after your if

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
avg = []
count = 0
while True:
    x = float(input('Enter a number(interger or float) :'))
    if x == -999:
        list = avg 
        sum(list)
        len(list)
        avg = float(sum(list))/len(list)
        print ('The average of', count, 'is ' "%0.2f" % avg)
        break
    else:
        avg.append(x)
        count +=1
```

You just need to add the number to the list to be averaged after you have checked whether its the terminating number.
You might not even need to put an `else` here since you are using `break`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is reading the first value before entering the loop:

```
numbers = []
numbers.append(float(input('Enter a number(interger or float) :')))
#the last argument given is the one you check for exeting the loop
while avg[-1] != -999:
    numbers.append(float(input('Enter a number(interger or float) :')))
length = len(numbers)
avg = float(sum(numbers)/length)
print ('The average of', str(length) , 'is ' "%0.2f" % avg)
```

not sure if this is better but it is an option if you want to avoid checking the if statement every iteration

Comment: Thanks for the response. The more the better, that way I can use this for future reference.